# SKSpriteNode or SKShapeNode for Circular Object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Does anyone have any guidance how to create a SpriteKit object that looks like a circle with circular physics properties? I've considered using SKShapeNode, yet after reading comments in documentation like this one "the SKSpriteNode class offers higher performance than this class, so use shape nodes sparingly" here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode, I'm reluctant to use SKShapeNode.

I have code to create an SKSpriteNode from image that makes it look like a circle...

```
sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:spriteImage)
```

...and I've applied a circular physics body...

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (width / 2))
```

I've set properties such as allowrotation, affectedbygravity and isDynamic to true in the physics body...

```
physics = sprite.physicsBody
physics.affectedByGravity = true
physics.allowsRotation = true
physics.isDynamic = true
```

The circle SKSpriteNode still behaves like a square. Instead of rolling like a wheel, the object flops like a square.

Comment: When you say it doesn't roll like a wheel, how are you trying to move it?

Comment: The movement comes from gravity. Since the SKSpriteNode has a circular physics body, when placed on a stationary object (ie not affected by gravity, etc.) that's angled, I thought it would roll down it like a wheel. Right now it doesn't roll. It still is behaving like a square. I know it is behaving like a square because I can put it on top of another square SKSpriteNode that's angled, but to make it rotate I have to put part of it hanging off the side enough so that gravity rotates it off. With the way it is angled, a circle would just roll. If a drawing would help, I can do that.

Comment: So it's sliding down the slope rather than rolling?

Comment: Friction is set high that it doesn't slide very much, but yes, it slides a bit. It doesn't roll.

Comment: Sounds like the physicsBody isn't getting properly set, but it could be bad friction settings or something.  The first thing I would do is turn on showsPhysics for the SKView this is presenting in to make sure you've at least got the right shapes for your physics bodies.  If you see a square, you know you need to figure out why the physicsBody isn't being set.  If it is, then I'd start looking at your friction and mass type properties.  Another possibility is that you've got both - a parent has a physicsBody that the wheel is attached to, or some other body affecting things outside the wheel.

Comment: cc, you were right. The original physics body was set to a circle, then at some point in the code it was changed back into a square. It is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

cc was right. The original physics body was set to a circle, then at some point in the code the physics body was changed back into a square. I fixed that part of the code and it is working now. Thanks!